# Redirect en.example.com to example.com/index.php?language=en

Tags: mod-rewrite, multilingual, lighttpd

I would like redirect addresses that start with:

```
en.example.com/somefile.php
```

to:

```
example.com/somefile.php?language=en
```

Using mod_rewrite module in lighttpd. Until now I got this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^en\.(.*)\.com$" {
        url.rewrite-once = (
                "^/(.*)"
                =>
                "/$1?language=en"
        )
}
```

But this does not seem to be working. What to do to make this work?

Comment: Why don’t you extract the language from the HTTP host with PHP (`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`)?

Comment: @Gumbo - Without different subdomains search engines don't get that there are more languages on this site.

Comment: @tomaszs: How about putting the language identifier into the URL path instead like `http://example.com/en/…`? And don’t forget proper language declaration in HTTP and HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^en\.([^/.]+)\.com$" {
    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^/([^?]*)(\?(.*))?" => "http://%1/$1?language=en&$3"
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$HTTP["host"] !~ "^(en|fr)\.([^.]+\.com)$ {
    url.rewrite-once = (
      "^/(.*)" => "http://%2/$1&language=%1" 
    )
  }
```

This should rewrite subdomains en. and/or fr. to whatever domain (including the TLD) with the  URL string intact, and append the language parameter.

Examples:

```
http://en.example.com            -> http://example.com/&language=en
http://fr.example.com/directory/ -> http://example.com/directory/&language=fr
```

Comment: `&language=en` in `http://example.com/&language=en` is part of the URL path and not part of the URL query.

Comment: True. You can use “?” in place of “&” but that breaks if the URL already has parameters.

Example: `http://en.example.com/?param1=12345 -> http://example.com/?param1=12345?language=en`

Do you need to handle URLs with query string parameters already?

Answer (score 0):

try following.. if it works for you..

$HTTP["host"] =~ "^en.([^.]+.com[a-z0-9-]+.php)$" {
        url.rewrite-once = (
                "^/(.*)"
                =>
                "/$1?language=en"
        )
}